# Nearly new computer build not working after 9-months no use

Tags: cpu, shutdown, cooling, temperature, computer-building

I bought a computer probably about a year and a half ago now and due to some unforeseen extensions in military training, I have been away from home for about 9 months. Well I came back home to visit recently and discovered the computer wasn't working:

It worked fine for about 5 minutes on first power and I noticed things were kind of slow and just other signs of poor performance so I went for a reboot. Upon reboot and every time thereafter, I barely make it to the BIOS menu and then it shuts off. However, I was able to keep it powered on long enough to get a picture of the settings that I think will help diagnose the culprit:

[image]

Notice the CPU Temperature - this is WAY hotter than I would expect the Desktop to be (hell, that's hotter than my laptop most of the time). Since I'm pretty sure the cause has to do with lack of use, the main component I thought of that would be affected by this was the liquid cooler. Somehow or for whatever reason, I think the coolant has stagnated and is not recirculating or something causing that severe temperature and I anticipate that some temperature sensor in the M/B is then triggering the shutdown since I read that if a CPU has sustained enough damage from heat to shut down, it is unlikely you would be able to power the computer back on at all.

Luckily, the liquid cooler was only about $80 but its directly thermal-pasted to the CPU so if I have to remove it I'm not sure what precautions I should take or if this is even possible?
I would appreciate any help/suggestions for resolving this issue or sharing of similar stories, etc. I would like to return home with a list of ideas to go through because right now I'm so scared to cause a new problem or misdiagnose the issue, etc that I'm tempted to just take it to GeekSquad even though I think I could probably do a better job still.

Please find my other specs below:
[image]

I appreciate any/all help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Thermal paste isn't a paste in the sense of glue. It [fills the holes between the cpu and heatsink](https://tpucdn.com/articles/134/images/contactarea.jpg) to transfer heat. You can remove it and then clean/reapply new thermal paste

Answer (score 1):

CPU is too high for idle, unless your overclocking even then.

Get some more thermal paste, and rubbing alcohol.

Turn everything off.

Take off the CPU cooler.

Clean the bottom with rubbing alcohol.

Clean the CPU the same way.

Re-apply the new thermal paste.

Put everything back together and test.

Misc:

Some CPU coolers come with a plastic sheet over them to prevent dust from accumulating before thermal paste is applied.  Did you forgot to take it off?

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! This will be the first thing I try. I did use the thermal paste that came with the cooler the notion of which I heard mixed reviews i.e. "aftermarket" thermal paste is far superior.

Comment: Just to clear up a possible ambuity in this (correct) post - do not use too much thermal paste - just enough for the lightest covering of the CPU - thermal paste is not that good a conductor, you want just enough to remove air gaps between the CPU and cooler.

Comment: I definitely took off the plastic sheet and it was working some 5-6 months like a gem prior to my 9-month absence

Comment: @sterlingbutters If you are not overclocking your system, any regular thermal paste should work fine.  If you are overclocking, then yes, a good thermal paste can be superior.  You may want to spend some time on Google looking at comparisons and how to apply it if you have not done so before.

Comment: @davidgo No intentions of overclocking but now that it looks like I will need to buy some new thermal paste, I will definitely do the research

Comment: @SterlingButters  If it was working 5-6 months with the hardware you listed above then something happened to the water cooler.  I would double check the power cables from the CPU cooler to make sure there all still connected.  Also if you had another computer you could connect the cooler to you could see if the pump is still running via USB header.

Comment: I don't see the power cables just randomly disconnecting but I'll be sure to add that to the list. And no I don't have another computer, is there another way to check? Besides the power, what else could go wrong with the cooler you think?

Comment: @SterlingButters  Something happened to cause it to stop conducting heat.  If the pump fail or was not working for some reason that would cause heat build up.  If the liquid drained out or evaporated that would be an issue.(this is highly unlikely)

Comment: @cybernard Roger that - I'll post back once I get home and can take a look